# How to make like button on Facebook for other fan pages with iframe

Tags: php, html, facebook, button, iframe

I'm wondering if there is a way to make like buttons on Facebook in iframe tabs about other fan pages that works because the old one seems not to work any more. If you add other pages like buttons Facebook block it automatically...

For example:

In the main page I create a iframe tab and on it I put 4 different like button of 4 different fan pages.

Is that possible any more? Do you have the code or other way to do that?

Comment: Sounds spammy, and like Facebook is prohibiting this for a reason.